# Is there extensible structured file analyzer, like network analysis tools?

Tags: file-format

There are many network analysis tools like `Wireshark`, `Sniffer Pro`, `Omnipeak` which can dump the packet data in structured manner. I'm just writing my own file analyzer for general purpose, which can dump JPEG, PNG, EXE, ELF, ASN.1 DER encoded files, etc. in tree style. There are so many file formats in the world that I can't handle them all. So I'm wondering if there's some software already there, with pluggable architecture and a large established file format repository?

Bonus: If it's for Linux and free.

Comment: A couple useful utilities on Linux: `file` tells you the type of a file, and `strings` prints strings in a (possibly binary) file.  Although both are a **far** cry from what you're asking, they're nonetheless good to know about.

Comment: Thank you, I've also posted a non-related question in the english site: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7523/what-is-a-far-cry  o_o

Answer (score 2):

[Synalyze It](http://www.synalysis.net) is a hex editor with pluggable grammar files for file format analysis.  So far it's a pretty small repository though.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/). Easily extensible through .Net plugins.